# Behaviour of Listview not be totally clickable

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I am using Listview containing some views like imageview, textviews and buttons. I am using

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

to handle the click evens of the list items. However though the click works, it doesn't work for all rows. For some weird reasons, I am not able to click item 28 and 29. How can I get these rows too to be clickable. Thanks.

Comment: By default the button will be clickable, so the row have button will not trigger onItemClick.
Maybe this is your issue.

Comment: All the rows have button but the problem is some are clickable and others are not. I just don't understand the behaviour.

Comment: Can you add your adapter and the item layout code?

Comment: Can you post your listview layout and adapter layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys for all the help. I didn't do much but I got to know the reason why some of the rows are not clickable. The row becomes unclickable whenever one of the other clickable views like imageView or buttons is assigned to a null value from my database. As far as there's a value or data to fill these views, the row is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding these lines in the parent layout of listview element

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

And add these lines in the textview,imageview & buttons which you using

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focuseable="false"
android:focuseableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I can't set clickable to false for the other views in the listView because I need them clickable for other actions. Is there any way to have every row in the listview clickable and child views clickable as well? Thanks

Comment: then directly use in adapter button or imageview or textview setonClickListener. This will work